# Any way to specify type to self? Or workaround "Types of property are incompatible."

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two classes, `Line` and `Wall`. Line class is parent and have `collide` function witch accept only array of Lines, and only return it filtered back.
Wall class does the same, but for Walls.

```
class Line {
    public start: Point
    public end: Point

    constructor(start: Point, end: Point) {
        this.start = start
        this.end = end
    }

    collide(lines: Line[]):Line[] {
        return lines.filter((line) => {return true || false})
    }
}
```

And Wall class:

```
class Wall extends Line {
    public start: Point
    public end: Point
    public thickness: number

    private collideWith: Wall[]

    constructor(start: Point, end: Point,thickness: number) {
        super(start,end)
        this.thickness = thickness
    }

    collide(walls: Wall[]):Wall[] {
        return this.collideWith = walls.filter((wall) => {return true || false})
        // I would love if this could return just void
        // since it update private property only,
        // but returning Wall[] works too
    }
}
```

This code produces an error:

```
file.ts(line,7): error TS2415: Class 'Wall' incorrectly extends base class 'Line'.
Types of property 'collide' are incompatible.
    Type '(walls: Wall[]) => void' is not assignable to type '(lines: Line[]) => Line[]'.
      Types of parameters 'walls' and 'lines' are incompatible.
        Type 'Wall[]' is not assignable to type 'Line[]'.
          Type 'Wall' is not assignable to type 'Line'.
            Types of property 'collide' are incompatible.
              Type '(walls: Wall[]) => void' is not assignable to type '(lines: Line[]) => Line[]'.
                Types of parameters 'walls' and 'lines' are incompatible.
                  Type 'Wall[]' is not assignable to type 'Line[]'.
                    Type 'Wall' is not assignable to type 'Line'.
```

How to deal with this kind of situation?

Comment: it compiles for me, what tsc version you have? try upgrade your tsc

Comment: @dannielum I use sublime text to compile it, and it should use the one from npm. After typing "npm v tsc" I got: version: '1.20150623.0' (on one of many lines)

Comment: @dannielum and `npm view typescript version` returned 1.8.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code:

```
    // I would love if this could return just void
    // since it update private property only,
    // but returning Wall[] works too
```

For the child class to return void the parent class must also return `void`. This is because of OO polymorphism. Consider:

```
var foo:Line;
var bar: Wall;
foo = bar; // polymorphism. After all `Wall` is just `Line` with other stuff
var x = foo.collide(); // Actually calls `bar.collide`. So signatures must be compatible.
```

## Update (using `self[]` type):

Its called `this` type in TypeScript. Here is a sample:

```
interface Point {x:number,y:number}

class Line {
    public start: Point
    public end: Point

    constructor(start: Point, end: Point) {
        this.start = start
        this.end = end
    }

    collide(lines: this[]) {
        return lines.filter((line) => {return true || false});
    }
}

class Wall extends Line {
    public start: Point
    public end: Point
    public thickness: number

    private collideWith: Wall[]

    constructor(start: Point, end: Point,thickness: number) {
        super(start,end)
        this.thickness = thickness
    }

    collide(walls: this[]) {
        return this.collideWith = walls.filter((wall) => {return true || false});
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? I fought that it call parent only if I add super.funcName(...params) at begening...

Comment: Yes it only calls parent if call to super is there. But the external world cannot be sure if `parent` is called or `child` is called due to polymorphism : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Subtyping

Comment: Ok... and can I do something like self[] as type?

Comment: Yes you can do `this[]` type. I've added it as an update 

Comment: Thanks just, `collide(lines: Line[])` had to be replaced with `collide(lines: this[])`

Comment: @Akxe thanks! I've fixed the answer based on that suggestion as well so there is no need for a type assertion anymore